# How do I pronounce $10^{-12}$?

Tags: terminology

I am aware that $10^{12} = 1,000,000,000,000$, which is called a Trillion.

$10^{-12} = \frac{1}{1,000,000,000,000}$, which means 1 divided by a Trillion.

The question is how do I pronounce it. Would I speak it as "ten to the power of negative **twelfth**", "ten to the power of negative **twelve**" or something else better? Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first form seems very iffy. I'd go with the second one.

Comment: I would say "Ten to the negative twelfth."

Comment: I'd say: "ten to the minus twelve".

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  How about a trillionth?

Comment: Once my math prof said, "Notion is important, not notation". So basically it doesn't matter what you say about $10^{-12}$ if it is understandable then mathematicians will understand that.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner's suggestion is good, provided you're happy your audience will understand trillion to mean $10^{12}$ [rather than](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales#Comparison) $10^{18}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Sujit's comment that there are many acceptable pronunciations and you shouldn't stress too much about picking the "best" one. As a native speaker all of the following sound fine to me:

- ten to the negative twelfth
- ten to the negative twelfth power
- ten to the negative twelve
- ten to the power of negative twelve
- ten to the minus twelve
- one ee negative twelve (ok, maybe avoid this one around the pure mathematicians ;))

and I'm sure there are many other perfectly fine variations and permutations of the above.

Answer (score 1):

I would say: *"ten to the negative twelfth"*. Or, to be more precisley, you can add the *"pico"* prefix before the unit of measure.

Comment: Thank you so much. Would you please give some reference?

Comment: @WXJ96163: see this Wikipedia's page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pico-.